# Pandas dataframe: Number of dates in group prior to row date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I would like to add a column in a dataframe that contains for each group ***G*** the number of distinct observations in variable `x` that happened before time `t`.
Note: `t` is in datetime format and missing values in the data are possible but can be ignored. The same `x` can appear multiple times in a group but then it is assigned the same date. The time assigned to `x` is not the same across groups.

I hope this example helps:

Input:

```
Group   x        t  

1       a      2013-11-01   
1       b      2015-04-03  
1       b      2015-04-03  
1       c      NaT  
2       a      2017-03-01  
2       c      2013-11-06   
2       d      2015-04-26  
2       d      2015-04-26  
2       d      2015-04-26
2       b      NaT
```

Output:

```
Group   x        t         Number of unique x before time t

1       a      2013-11-01      0
1       b      2015-04-03      1
1       b      2015-04-03      1
1       c      NaT             NaN
2       a      2017-03-01      2
2       c      2013-11-06      0
2       d      2015-04-26      1
2       d      2015-04-26      1
2       d      2015-04-26      1
2       b      NaT             NaN
```

The dataset is quite large so I wonder if there is any vectorized way do this (e.g. using `groupby`).

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you can do it like this using a custom designed function using `merge` to do a self-join, `groupby` and `nunique` to count unique values:

```
def countunique(x):
    df_out = x.merge(x, on='Group')\
              .query('x_x != x_y and t_y < t_x')\
              .groupby(['x_x','t_x'])['x_y'].nunique()\
              .reset_index()
    result = x.merge(df_out, left_on=['x','t'], 
                     right_on=['x_x','t_x'],
                     how='left')
    result = result[['Group','x','t','x_y']]
    result.loc[result.t.notnull(),'x_y'] = result.loc[result.t.notnull(),'x_y'].fillna(0)
    return result.rename(columns={'x_y':'No of unique x before t'})

df.groupby('Group', group_keys=False).apply(countunique)
```

Output:

```
   Group  x          t  No of unique x before t
0      1  a 2013-11-01                      0.0
1      1  b 2015-04-03                      1.0
2      1  b 2015-04-03                      1.0
3      1  c        NaT                      NaN
0      2  a 2017-03-01                      2.0
1      2  c 2013-11-06                      0.0
2      2  d 2015-04-26                      1.0
3      2  d 2015-04-26                      1.0
4      2  d 2015-04-26                      1.0
5      2  b        NaT                      NaN
```

Explanation:

For each group,

1. Perform a self-join using merge on 'Group'
2. Filter result of self join only getting those time before the
   current record.
3. Use groupby with nunique to count only unique values of x from
   self-join.
4. Merge count of x back to the original dataframe keep all rows using
   how='left'
5. Fill NaN values with zero where there is time on a recourd
6. Rename column headings

Comment: Thank you very much! It works as it should, but runs slow for a large amount of groups (~10000).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another method.

- The initial sort makes it so `fillna` will work later on.
- Create `df2`, which calculates the unique number of days within each group before that date.
- Merge the number of days back to the original `df`. `fillna` then takes care of the days which were duplicated (the sort ensures this happens properly)
- Dates with `NaT` were placed at the end for the `cumsum` so just reset them to `NaN`

If you want to reorder at the end to the original order, just sort the index `df.sort_index(inplace=True)`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = df.sort_values(by=['Group', 't'])
df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df.t)

df2 = df
df2 = df2[df2.t.notnull()]
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()
df2['temp'] = 1
df2['num_b4'] = df2.groupby('Group').temp.cumsum()-1

df = df.merge(df2[['num_b4']], left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
df['num_b4'] = df['num_b4'].fillna(method='ffill')
df.loc[df.t.isnull(), 'num_b4'] = np.NaN

#   Group  x          t  num_b4
#0      1  a 2013-11-01     0.0
#1      1  b 2015-04-03     1.0
#2      1  b 2015-04-03     1.0
#3      1  c        NaT     NaN
#5      2  c 2013-11-06     0.0
#6      2  d 2015-04-26     1.0
#7      2  d 2015-04-26     1.0
#8      2  d 2015-04-26     1.0
#4      2  a 2017-03-01     2.0
#9      2  b        NaT     NaN
```

IIUUC for the new cases, you want to change a single line in the above code.

```
# df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(['Group', 't'])
```

With that, the same day that has multiple `x` values assigned to it does not cause the number of observations to increment. See the output for Group 3 below, in which I added 4 rows to your initial data.

```
Group   x        t  
3       a      2015-04-03
3       b      2015-04-03
3       c      2015-04-03
3       c      2015-04-04 

## Apply the Code changing the drop_duplicates() line
    Group  x          t  num_b4
0       1  a 2013-11-01     0.0
1       1  b 2015-04-03     1.0
2       1  b 2015-04-03     1.0
3       1  c        NaT     NaN
5       2  c 2013-11-06     0.0
6       2  d 2015-04-26     1.0
7       2  d 2015-04-26     1.0
8       2  d 2015-04-26     1.0
4       2  a 2017-03-01     2.0
9       2  b        NaT     NaN
10      3  a 2015-04-03     0.0
11      3  b 2015-04-03     0.0
12      3  c 2015-04-03     0.0
13      3  c 2015-04-04     1.0
```

Comment: Thank you. I like the solution, as it is quite fast. However, there is one issue in case of varying X which have the same date:

Comment: Thank you. I like the solution, as it is quite fast. However, there is one issue in case of varying x which have the same date (a case I have not thought of previously, but should where num_b4 should have the same value): For example, if in observation #2, x is replaced with S, then num_b4 should show still 1 (since only x=a is before), but it would show 2.  Have you any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @JanN. See the update. You just need to change the `drop_duplicates` line and you should get the desired output you want.

Comment: Thank you for the modification. In the last line (13) of your example, the theoretical result should be 3 (since a,b,c happen before). Any quick-fix idea?

Comment: @JanN. It should be possible to do. You should just need to figure out how many days you need to add to `df2['temp']` before calculating the cumsum. If you just want distinct `x` you can figure that out with `df.groupby(['Group', 't']).x.nunique()-1` or if you want the total number of observations you can use `df.groupby(['Group', 't']).x.count()-1`. The issue, is that you then want to add this number to the NEXT DATE in the group. I'm having trouble doing that, though I think it can be accomplished with `merge_asof()`. You might have luck asking that in another question.